# reader.readAsDataURL resulting in a defectuous base64 string?

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader

I am using this javascript code to read and upload a file to server:

```
var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
  var bytes = reader.result;
  var ext = file.name.split(".").pop();
  xhr.send("bytes="+bytes+"&type="+ext);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

When I check which parameters are being sent to server (in the developer console), I see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yrdp.jpg

which causes an Illegal base64 character error (I think caused by the spaces in the string).

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using `readAsBinaryString` rather?

Comment: with this I got a base64 string too? I need those in the server side.

Comment: It doesn't, but you could use `btoa` to convert it afterwards. It's just an idea you could try ^^

Comment: I just tried that right now, but the same error happens (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20`) and the same spaces being shown in the string.

Answer (score 3):

`readAsDataURL` doesn't produce a clean base64 string, but rather produces a string in the format:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

This format is known as a [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).
You can obtain the raw base64-data by splitting:

```
const base64 = reader.result.split (",").pop ()
```

If your data is still invalid, use `readAsBinaryString` (which returns a File/Blog) and then use `window.btoa` to convert it to a base64 string.

Comment: I already doing that in the server side, after the data is sent, and that's what causing the error, because the base64-data have spaces which should not be there.

Comment: ok, another person suggested that in the comments, and I just tried this `readAsBinaryString` already, following his suggestion. But the same error happened.

Comment: Have you tried using btoa? Can you post your example image? I haven't experienced a problem like this before, readAsBinaryString should return valid binary data.

Comment: How I can run the example? I try download, but do not work on my machine (with chrome or firefox). In the web interface I don't find button to run the example.

Comment: It runs in the browser. Just open the console to see the result.